# The Peculiar File

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

So I was browsing through my computer files earlier and I found a file I'd not seen before. I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out what it's about.

This is where I found it:
[image: File Location]

This is its contents:
[image: The Trial]

What does it say? And what is it referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a

> nonogram.

The filled-in cells say (not perfectly clearly)

> THE GREAT ESCAPER. Presumably in homage to the PSE participant. The eye in the window's title bar is (credit to user TrojanByAccident in TSL chat for noticing this) a reference to the eye that appears in many of the grids of TGE's "WITLESS" puzzle that's currently bending the brains of many PSE folks.

Actual filled-in image:

> [image]

Comment: Right all around :)

Answer (score 8):

The grid looks like a game of [Descartes Enigma](http://www.kaser.com/descart.html) - perhaps that's where you found it on your computer?

The numbers labelling each row and column give the pattern of black cells in each row or column; different numbers correspond to groups of black cells which must have white cells in between.

The grid is $15\times21$, so we can fill in a few sets of black cells right away:

[image: take one]

Now I'm going to use light grey to indicate cells which are known to be white (as opposed to the white which is used for unknown cells), and fill in a load more. The logic is fairly simple, so I won't bother explaining every step. First progress report:

[image: take two]

Now we start by reading some of the middle rows from the left. Second progress report:

[image: take three]

Now we start from the "6,2,1,1" column. Third progress report:

[image: take four]

By now the solution has become quite clear, and the rest is easy to fill in:

[image: final solution]

And the final answer is

> [THE GREAT ESCAPER](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper).